# Band structure calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I want to do band structure calculation of Magnesium silicide for GGA  in `VASP`. Can anyone please help how to do this by setting initial `INCAR` tags and `KPOINTS` file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your structure is relaxed.

- The 1st step: self-consistent calculation to obtain converged charge density (uniform K mesh).
- The 2nd step: non-self-consistent calculation to obtain the eigenvalue along a high symmetry path by reading previous converged charge density.

PS: you can generate the high symmetry path with [VASPKIT](https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#pre-process-band-structure-pure-functional).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Shalini: You accepted the answer, so why don't you upvote it? Your quesiton might have been featured on the network-wide "hot network questions" since Jack answered it so quickly, but this only happens if the answer has enough upvotes. I'm surprised I'm the only one that upvoted this!

Answer (score 0):

First, the lattice optimization is performed, and then the atomic position is optimized. After the stable position is obtained, the static calculation can be performed, and then the k-point path is set to obtain the energy band.